# Close ng-bootstrap date picker when click outside in angular2

Tags: angular, datepicker, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap4 datepicker https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker

I want to close `datepicker` when click outside of calendar. Right now when user select date then it will close.

My `HTML` file code is below:

```
<input ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker" (click)="d.toggle();" [formControl]="eventForm.controls['event_date']" value="12/03/2017" type="text" [readonly]="true" autocomplete="off">
```

I try to adding `(click)="d.close();"` in body tag. But it's also close when i try to change month and year from calendar.
What change i have to do either in `HTML` or `component` to close this `datepicker` when user click outside of calendar?

Comment: Take a look at this - https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/783 - I'm not sure if the issue has been fixed correctly, as it seems only toggle has been added, but there are some workarounds in that thread.

Answer (score 12):

Yea, I had the same problem... This works well for me:

component HTML:

```
<input placeholder="{{ task.deadline.year }}-{{ task.deadline.month }}-{{ task.deadline.day }}" name="date" id="date" [(ngModel)]="task.deadline" ngbDatepicker  #d="ngbDatepicker" (click)="!completed && d.toggle(); $event.stopPropagation();" (document:click)="closeFix($event, d)" readonly>
```

and the TS (the only thing that you need is the closeFix() function):

```
closeFix(event, datePicker) {
  if(event.target.offsetParent == null)
    datePicker.close();
  else if(event.target.offsetParent.nodeName != "NGB-DATEPICKER")
    datePicker.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the on-mouseleave event to close the datepicker when the user leave the div

```
<input on-mouseleave="d.close()" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker" (click)="d.toggle();" [formControl]="eventForm.controls['event_date']" value="12/03/2017" type="text" [readonly]="true" autocomplete="off">
```

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

Since 3.0.0 version this problem was resolved with `[autoclose]="'outside'"`

```
<input type="text" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker" [autoclose]="'outside'"/>
```

[documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/api)

Answer (score 0):

In your component.ts,

```
    import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      host: {
        '(document:click)': 'closeDatepicker($event)',
      }
    })

    export class MyComponent {
      @ViewChild('d') eventDate;

      closeDatepicker(e) {
        if (!this.eventDate.isOpen() || (e.target.id === 'd' && e.target.id === 'dropdown-icon')
          || (e.target.offsetParent && e.target.offsetParent.localName.includes('ngb-datepicker'))
          || !(e.target.parentElement && e.target.parentElement.parentElement &&
            !e.target.parentElement.parentElement.localName.includes('ngb-datepicker'))) {
          return;
        }
        if (this.eventDate.isOpen() && e.target.id !== 'd' && e.target.id !== 'dropdown-icon') {
          this.eventDate.close();
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seemed to be an old issue but thought to share my solution as well. We had the same issue but we were using Angular Web Element and we had to dig into the DOM element to find the **NGB-DATEPICKER** tagname. Below is the HTML file and typescript code

**HTML**

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary calendar" (click)="yed.toggle();ysd.close();$event.stopPropagation();" 
                (document:click)="closeFix($event, yed)" type="button">
                    <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>
```

**TYPESCRIPT**

```
closeFix(event, datePicker) {       
    if(event.target.offsetParent == null)
      datePicker.close();
    else if(this.clickedInNgbDatePicker(event.path))
      datePicker.close();      
  }

  clickedInNgbDatePicker(eventPath){
    let datePickerClicked = true; 
    eventPath.forEach(function(item){  
      datePickerClicked = (item.tagName != "NGB-DATEPICKER" && datePickerClicked)
    });
    return datePickerClicked;
  }
```